# Lonely Multiplication

Tags: code-golf, math

Based on [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/236520) from Code Review.

Given precisely three positive integers, return the product of all of the distinct inputs. If none of the inputs are distinct, return 1. That is, implement the function:

\$ f(a,b,c) = \cases{1 & $a = b = c $ \\ a & $ b = c $ \\ b & $ a = c $ \\ c & $ a = b $ \\ a b c & otherwise } \$

Shortest code in each language wins.

#### Test cases

```
a, b, c -> f(a,b,c)
7, 7, 7 -> 1
3, 3, 5 -> 5
2, 6, 6 -> 2
3, 4, 3 -> 4
1, 2, 3 -> 6
12, 9, 16 -> 1728
```

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
¢ÏP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0KLD/QH//0cb6yiYA1EsAA)

```
¢       # count occurences of each number
 Ï      # keep only those where the count is 1
  P     # product (1 if the list is empty)
```

Comment: I had this exact solution prepared when I saw it in the Sandbox last week. Of course it had to go live yesterday evening, haha. ;) Obvious +1 from me.

Answer (score 11):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>46</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>43</s></sup> 42 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [79037662](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89930/79037662)!!!

```c
f(a,b,c){a=a^b?a^c?b^c?a*b*c:a:b:b^c?c:1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1EnSSdZszrRNjEuyT4xLtk@CYgTtZK0kq0SrZKsQLxkK0Pr2v@5iZl5GprVXAVFmXklaRpKqikxeUo6aRrmOgogpKlpjU3KGIiwSRmDpUyxSRnpKJgBEQ5dJjgMNNRRMIJK1f4HAA)

Comment: I believe you can use ```a^c``` (bitwise xor) to check for equality which is shorter than ```c==a```. Note that you'd have to flip the other parts of the ternary.

Comment: @79037662 Yes, I have thought of that but my head's still spinning from getting this to work! T_T

Comment: Here's a version for 45 bytes, I think it can be reduced further but I'm not sure. https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1EnSSdZszrRNtHWNsk@ydY22d7QKtkKzEi0So5LtE/UStICCljX/s9NzMzT0KzmKijKzCtJ01BSTYnJU9JJ0zDXUQAhTU1rbFLGQIRNyhgsZYpNykhHwQyIcOgywWGgoY6CEVSq9j8A

Comment: @79037662 Nice one - thanks! :-)

Comment: 42 bytes: https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1EnSSdZszrRNjEuyT4xLtk@CYgTtZK0kq0SrZKsQLxkK0Pr2v@5iZl5GprVXAVFmXklaRpKqikxeUo6aRrmOgogpKlpjU3KGIiwSRmDpUyxSRnpKJgBEQ5dJjgMNNRRMIJK1f4HAA

Comment: @79037662 Well done - we got there! :-)

Comment: I have a n00b question. What's the "a=" doing there? It looks like it's a golf replacement for "return " but if so it's new to me. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamChalcraft gcc uses the same register for the first function parameter and the return value if they're both `int`. So yes, it's a golf hack to simply assign the return value to the first parameter.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

```javascript
(a,b,c)=>a-b?b-c?c-a?a*b*c:b:a:b-c?c:1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZctBCsIwEIXhvaeYZVImlsS2QqDmLDNjK0ppihWvH6MBwQr/6n28Gz1plft1eZg5noc09kkRMoruT2Q4sJEghgJVXIlnT/6zeJskzmuchv0UL2pUR4R3WkNdg9394gEh1xZsN@gQulxB9/9s8rlgs0GL4L7YpRc)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 53 bytes

Takes input as `[a,b,c]`.

```javascript
A=>[[a,b,c]=A,1,a-b?a-c?a:b:c,a*b*c][new Set(A).size]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bczRCoIwFMbx@57iXDo5Ki41EEz2DF2OXZytGYpskVLQyy@DQSDB/@7H9030pMU8xvuaOX@1YeiC6M5SEmo0qhNYImW6p8z01OrWIKU6NUo6@4KLXRPB8mV8WxWMd4ufbT77WzIk8oTwTTEGRQHlYcdHhK06cr1njtBsReZ/1tV2ELnac4nAf9yEDw)

#### Commented

```javascript
A =>                // A[] = input
  [                 // lookup table:
    [a, b, c] = A,  //   set size = 0 --> impossible, so use this slot
                    //   to split A[] into 3 distinct variables
    1,              //   set size = 1 --> return 1
    a - b ?         //   set size = 2 --> if a is not equal to b:
      a - c ?       //     if a is not equal to c:
        a           //       return a
      :             //     else:
        b           //       return b
    :               //   else:
      c,            //     return c
    a * b * c       //   set size = 3 --> return a * b * c
  ]                 //
  [new Set(A).size] // index into lookup table = size of the set
```

Comment: Thanks for including the second solution. It's way cooler than the fully golfed version.

Comment: For the case where two are the same, `a^b^c` gives the unique one. That saves 8 bytes in the second version.

Answer (score 7):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
*/@-.}./.~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcw7CoAwEATQfk8xrRIj@VoEQ07gJSRBbGxs9epxF2SneQyzZ@8Nq8Y4l0k/etZv3667wtCiIMGUGU6BEwSBrELkCKw0nkuBJ6Ngf0QaqO7HVVrJ/EUuceMQEiyPo8jDJRi2A/UP)

```
     }./.~  group by value and remove one from each group
   -.       set subtract from input
*/          product
```

Comment: This is quite nice

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>40</s> 37 bytes

-3 bytes by taking input with `scan()`.

```r
prod(unique(x<-scan())^2,1/x)^!!sd(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcrLCoAgFIThfU9hu3NgItIum3qVICyhjV0F8eUtIWI2Hz9zRiMGYZzV97pZChCXnuzwBw4c93Obydn1cAv5vkgHYh4lqtLzmOfXTJ6jIU0d3jFnyQoKzWeJFu3fa6jPFWRyfAA)

`sd(x)` computes the standard deviation (which is 0 iff all entries are equal), so `!!sd(x)` is `TRUE` if some entries are different, and `FALSE` if all are equal.

- if all entries are different, then `unique(x)==x`, so we are down to `prod(x)^1`
- if 2 entries are equal, then the corresponding value gets cancelled out between `unique(x)^2` and `1/x`, so we are left with the sole "lonely" value
- if all 3 entries are equal, then we have `(...)^0` which is 1.

This is shorter than anything I could come up with based on `table`, `tabulate`, `duplicated` or `rle(sort())`.

Comment: I had the obvious 47 bytes with `duplicated`; I did not even come close to this approach!

Comment: I think I've pipped you to 39 with `rle(sort())`, don't have the chance to fully bugtest it right now though. Apparently `prod(numeric(0)) == 1` so it might be solid: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v6AoP0VDI9G2KCdVozi/qESjODkxT0MTCFTKohUTVXJU9VWNYjX/m3KZcZn/BwA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @CriminallyVulgar The main reason for the difference is that you are using `scan()` to take input (which is surely fine). With `scan()`, my solution goes down to 37 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v6AoP0WjNC@zsDRVo8JGtzg5MU9DUzPOSMdQv0IzTlGxOEWjQvO/sYKJgul/AA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @RobinRyder Ah, I made an error converting yours to `scan()`, mine is significantly longer with the `function()` format. Definitely a lot more tedious to test with `scan()`, I don't blame you for not using it originally.

Comment: @RobinRyder I was massively overcomplicating my indexing at the ends, so here's 36: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v6AoP0VDI9G2KCdVozi/qESjODkxT0MTCFTKohNVcmyMYjX/myqYKZj/BwA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @CriminallyVulgar Well done! Worth posting separately IMO.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 bytes

*Thanks to Adám and Bubbler in chat for helping golf this*

```apl
×/∪*1=⊢∘≢⌸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhMPT9R91rNIytH3UtehRx4xHnYse9ewASikYKRgrmHCBaCALSJuAIBcA)

#### Explanation:

```apl
×/             ⍝ Reduce by multiplication
  ∪            ⍝ The unique values of the input
   *           ⍝ To the power of
    1=         ⍝ Whether one is equal to
        ≢      ⍝ The length of
      ⊢∘ ⌸     ⍝ The indexes of each unique element
```

Comment: These days (18.0+), `×/∪*=Ö≢⌸` [works](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=f%E2%86%90%C3%97%2F%E2%88%AA*%3D%E2%8D%A5%E2%89%A2%E2%8C%B8%20%E2%8B%84%20f%202%203%204%20%E2%8B%84%20f%202%202%203%20%E2%8B%84%20f%204%204%204&run).

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```python
lambda l:eval("(%sin[%s,%s]or %s)*"*3%(l*4)+"1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCsMgEADAu69YBGHX7kVNEwjkJW0PliZEsEaiTenrbZjL5F9dt2TbAhPcW/Tv58tDHOfDR5SoSkg3VViVx7aDKqSldgqj7ugijaT2XUOcwYx5D6nCgiHlT0WiNvBJOHZ8FZZ77s937IRhy@4P)

Takes in a tuple. The idea is similar to [an answer in the Code Review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236573/56493), which can be golfed to:

**51 bytes**

```python
lambda a,b,c:a**(b!=a!=c)*b**(c!=b!=a)*c**(a!=c!=b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcgxDoAgDADAr8BGm06ymfQl6tBiiCSKxODg6xHGu/LV485Ti4bN2k65dBcjpBRmQXRqWSwHQO0IlocBQ8fobmjlSbma6DDl8lYH0JaJPPntBw)

Each element is included in the product if it's different from the other two, with the power setting to a harmless `x**0 == 1` otherwise. We want to avoid writing the three similar terms being multiplied. Python unfortunately doesn't have a built-in list product without imports. So, we turn to `eval` shenanigans.

We use a longer expression that use logical short-circuiting:

**60 bytes**

```python
lambda a,b,c:(a in[b,c]or a)*(b in[c,a]or b)*(c in[a,b]or c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrBCsMgEIThu0@xRw1ziTYJBPokaQ@rbYiQGgmG0qe3K3P5P5j8K9uRbF3pTo@688e/mBgeYdZMMS1Sz@MkNp32zQHc7MWhWb7NwdTvFvc39XM@Yyq06i6mfBVtTJ0gUw4Og7IYMUrf4FQPC/cH)

In this expression, the variable names cycle through `a,b,c` in that order four times. So, by tripling the format string `"(%sin[%s,%s]or %s)*"` and plugging in the input tuple repeated four times, we get the desired expression. We just need to append a `"1"` to deal with the trailing multiplication.

Comment: Very nice! I only found the 51 :)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman so *this* was it! I had the expression with the powers but I wasn't being able to write it in a short format!

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>72</del> <del>71</del> bytes

```php
sort($argv);[,$a,$b,$c]=$argv;echo$a-$b?$b-$c?$a*$b*$c:$a:($b-$c?$c:1);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcixCoAgEAbgl/kHDR2CXLTwQaLh7ojcFIte/4po@YavlaZzbq9n7ZcB9eO2aXUgB3aQbfkq7VIqyIMz2EMyaAAPkAiK5i@Jo02qGnTS8AA)

<del>Might be shorter without the `sort` but nested ternary operator precedence blows my mind.</del>

-1 byte thanks to @640KB

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 66 bytes

```php
fn($a,$b,$c)=>$a-$c?$a-$b?$b-$c?$a*$b*$c:$a:$b==$c?:$c:$b==$c?:$b;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc9Ba4MwFAfw8/Ip/pR3sOXVoqvtpks9DXYYrPe2lCSNyA4q09vYZ88S68CRR3j5Je8l6erOvZRd3QlBg@2HHhIn8XDCnsfAhQFsNlgfkAR/5BDZ3LPgKWPnY@7pdH7rS@a@DZ5wKPnnu9G9PjOSsdN07z59EpdC@CdW0lVNRIpJM5mlPJBakynDrEvS93xFekUmJ5WTltJTHlZ/qS6cb1W1X1aZOsL0a9X7DEt8C8CausVn3zZX25j2ZqNxi7E4D@dhwaAqQhzHdzy@Ha@vH@@F@BHOJX5kvw)

Kudos to @640KB for taming the ternary operator beast!

Comment: Think you can -1 byte removing the `$n=` https://tio.run/##LcixCoAgEAbgl/kHDR2CXLTwQaLh7ojcFIte/4po@YavlaZzbq9n7ZcB9eO2aXUgB3aQbfkq7VIqyIMz2EMyaAAPkAiK5i@Jo02qGnTS8AA

Comment: And here's a ternary version without the `sort()`! https://tio.run/##Vc9Ba4MwFAfw8/Ip/pR3sOXVoqvtpks9DXYYrPe2lCSNyA4q09vYZ88S68CRR3j5Je8l6erOvZRd3QlBg@2HHhIn8XDCnsfAhQFsNlgfkAR/5BDZ3LPgKWPnY@7pdH7rS@a@DZ5wKPnnu9G9PjOSsdN07z59EpdC@CdW0lVNRIpJM5mlPJBakynDrEvS93xFekUmJ5WTltJTHlZ/qS6cb1W1X1aZOsL0a9X7DEt8C8CausVn3zZX25j2ZqNxi7E4D@dhwaAqQhzHdzy@Ha@vH@@F@BHOJX5kvw

Comment: I think the $b==$c can be reduced down to $b-$c by inverting the ternary truth/false parts. Not sure if my brain can handle it.

Comment: What happens with subtraction is that it changes the order of operations of the chained ternaries and you'd have to put parenthesis around it, so it actually adds one byte.

Comment: though it only works when you want to end with a  `1`. The subtraction is better for the upper leaves.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>7</s>  6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḟœ-Q$P
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjvlHJ@sGqgT8P9z@qGnN///R0eY6CiAUy6UTbayjAESmIKaRjoIZEEFFTYASIKahjoIRiBkLAA)**

#### How?

```
ḟœ-Q$P - list, L
    $  - last two links as a monad:
   Q   -   de-duplicate (L)
 œ-    -   (L) multi-set difference (that)
ḟ      - (L) filter discard if in (that)
     P - product
```

---

**7**s:

```
ĠṖÐḟị⁸P
ḟṖƙ`F$P
```

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman was it that?

Comment: Basically, just reordered: `œ-QɓḟP`

Answer (score 4):

## Excel (Version 1911), <s>80 Bytes</s>, 42 Bytes

```
=PRODUCT(FILTER(A1#,COUNTIF(A1#,A1#)=1,1))
```

Input entered as a static column array (e.g. `={1;2;3}`) in cell `A1`

- Saved 38 bytes due to inspiration from Grimmy's 05AB1E solution.

Comment: How about `=PRODUCT(IFERROR(UNIQUE(A1#,,1),1))`?

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

```hs
f l=product[x|x<-l,filter(==x)l==[x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcm7CgIxEIXhVzmFhcJs4XprnCcZUoS40eDsGrIRUvjsxgSEv/g452HX56Raq4dyTK/b22Upn3IdlHzQPKUtc9kpsxRj6mzDAkZMYcnYYLYRHiIXQs8Q5EBonTpHwrn1X4/t6NwTxk5Tv86rva91cDH@AA)

Pretty straightforward -- filter for elements that appear only once and take the product.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 36 bytes

```r
prod((a=rle(sort(scan())))$v[a$l<2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v6AoP0VDI9G2KCdVozi/qESjODkxT0MTCFTKohNVcmyMYjX/myqYKZj/BwA)

`rle()` shows its worth again. Feels like some parentheses could be golfed out somehow.

The fact that `prod()` of an empty numeric evaluates to 1 is the only reason this is efficient.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>[63](https://tio.run/##DchLCoAgEADQqwyunJAgXASBJ6kW9pGMyQmzsNNbb/nON20cdHFgYChkj2mxQN36WJKiEvXOPsgrRZnRcYQMPgCBd0D1zHdI/xvTIEfRCCxn9H852bdKKz0ilg8)</s> <s>[62](https://tio.run/##XcvLCsIwFIThvU8xZJVIKDTxAmKfRF3ESzByzCkxlfr0MSgIFv7Vx0z/yleOtnh02Bdy9@PZgTaXpyMp5qK5cYjykZMcleeEESGCEDyoOfEQc/WtUZxEK1TpU6ji5W6tYWsHpWY/sx9b/pnRWNWmu8X022qYr5U3)</s> 61bytes

```
lambda l:prod(x for x in l if l.count(x)<2)
from math import*
```

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##PclBCoMwEEbhvaf4l0kRobopRU9iu4iVwUCSGYYI6emjuHD5vif/vHEaXqKVMOFTg4vL6hDeoryaAmJFgU8I8ITQ/XhP2RQ79rYh5Yjo8gYfhTU/qqg/L5n52fbt8LW2ueXsS@oB)!

Thanks @FryAmTheEggman for saving me 1 byte.

Comment: You can use `<2` instead of `==1`. I also recommend looking through the code review responses - some of them can make for good golfing! :)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman thanks! Also, you think so? A first glance didn't show me anything very promising. Most answers used a LOT of if/else or imports...

Comment: I actually know there is something shorter :) Yours is different and works for any number of arguments, but you can save bytes by using that there are only 3 inputs! (Since it'll be totally different, if you find one I recommend posting another answer)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman shaved 1 more byte but still not what you were talking about

Answer (score 3):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 31 bytes

```
...{{*}*}:m;m\.|m/-m\.|,1=\1\if
```

This was... a lot more difficult than I thought it would be. Can be optimized. So much so, that I don't really want to give this much of an explanation.

Here's the process:

Take your input array and make 3 more copies of it. Make a function m, which multiplies the elements in an array together. Do that to the first array, then eliminate dupes from a second (keeping one of each). Perform m on it, then divide it from the first number. You should have the duplicate number (if there's only one pair dupe). Remove it rom your array, then return the last number. If the "suspected dupe" is 1, then just multiply again and output. If, when you remove all of the "suspected dupe"s, you're left with an array of size 1, just output 1 instead.

This was incredibly and probably needlessly complicated, but I couldn't find any good GolfScript shortcuts besides the multiplication bit. PITA.

[Try it online, I guess](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkfbapgrGAc@19PT6@6WqtWq9Yq1zo3Rq8mV18XROkY2sYYxmSm/f8PAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 44 bytes

```powershell
,1+($args|group|? C* -eq 1|% N*)-join'*'|iex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/dCoJAEIXv9ykGWXPX1gs1DYJI6L5XiKjNDEnzhwTXZ7fZzW04zMB3ZoaZuvrIpn3IspzpHfYwziJcM3pp8lblTdXX6gBHHwL5hlC5cPJ58KyKl@d7qpDDPBGSMQIYgoUCy1YY8YUlmsVCK7Es0gxTirJss/RhjS1LNcOlkWEcFLgwGo/KoZbXTt4EmEvxbnr@OY1s@7JDsMJ3Mm0a7lC2WPjJf5zv7IBDpvkL)

where `|? C* -eq 1` means `|? Count -eq 1` and `|% N*` means `|% Name`.

---

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 45 bytes

```powershell
$p=1;$args|group|? C* -eq 1|%{$p*=$_.Name};$p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9hC4JADIa/368YMkPlCtQ0SCSh7/0Fkbrsg@F1KgXqb7fd5TVeNnjebWyyfQvVPUTTLHiHHMYFZR5mWKm6m2rVDnI6wTmArXhBOLkjyiDHcnepnmLOUC4zY4XHgIJ7Iady4Eb@yhLNYq6VWBZpRiklWbZf@6jGlqWa0dLIMB8mcGE0HoqPFNde3DiYS@lwLH@OEt3Q9AQ29E@hTcMd9FaLPvmP@0c74LB5@QI)

Comment: Ah, that's really clever. I was playing around with something similar, but couldn't get it functional.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes

```
#&@@Times@@Tally@#~Cases~{_,1}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X1nNwSEkMze1GEgl5uRUOijXOScWpxbXVcfrGNaq/Q8oyswriU6LrjbXAcLa2FguuIixjrGOKYqIkY6ZjhmaGhMdYxQRQx0jsMh/AA)

Comment: `#&@@` and `{a_,1}->a` use the same number of characters to take first but the rule has lower precedence than the infix operator.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 27 bytes

```perl6
{[*] .Bag.grep(0=>1)>>.key}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OlorVkHPKTFdL70otUDDwNbOUNPOTi87tbL2f3FipYIeUFVafhGXhrmOAghp6nBpGOsoAJEpiGmko2AGRCCmIZBtqaNgCOT8BwA)

(Using a `Pair` as matcher compares only values and ignores the key.)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>92</del> 79 bytes

```php
fn($a)=>array_product(array_keys(array_intersect(array_count_values($a),[1])));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc5dS8MwFAbga/MrXkYvGsgYrftQaueV4IXg7rtSQpbSqSQhSYUh/vaa1CodnIuT5@R8mM4MD4@mMyRpy6FVacJpuefW8ktjrD71wqe/r3d5cVN6Vl5aJ/9LQvfKN5/8o5cuDmBVVlNKi6EgJPHSeYcSFbmpsGNjoGYAViss98ii37IYm7lvoucM2xBzz6f/69Ay93X0jMWWK9@OHvSeIRsnTXt3@R2pw4WttpKLLsV0KnchA8UXAaToNN6cVo1UQp9kOpYYFkd/9AuGpP2Tw/OheXp9Kcj38AM)

This isn't going to win for brevity, but just thought I'd try it entirely using chained PHP array functions.

Now using @Guillermo Phillips's suggestion for PHP 7.4 arrow function syntax to save 13 bytes.

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 66 bytes

```php
fn($a,$b,$c)=>$a-$c?$a-$b?$b-$c?$a*$b*$c:$a:$b==$c?:$c:$b==$c?:$b;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc9Ba4MwFAfw8/Ip/pR3sOXVoqvtpks9DXYYrPe2lCSNyA4q09vYZ88S68CRR3j5Je8l6erOvZRd3QlBg@2HHhIn8XDCnsfAhQFsNlgfkAR/5BDZ3LPgKWPnY@7pdH7rS@a@DZ5wKPnnu9G9PjOSsdN07z59EpdC@CdW0lVNRIpJM5mlPJBakynDrEvS93xFekUmJ5WTltJTHlZ/qS6cb1W1X1aZOsL0a9X7DEt8C8CausVn3zZX25j2ZqNxi7E4D@dhwaAqQhzHdzy@Ha@vH@@F@BHOJX5kvw)

And another crazy ternary version inspired by [@Guillermo Phillips's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199247/84624)!

Comment: It's a shame because the functions are powerful but verbose. Also, of course you can always use arrow functions: fn($a)=>..., but that's probably beside the point.

Comment: @GuillermoPhillips Yeah, they certainly weren't named for golfing.  `array_count_values()`?  Come on guys!  I've avoided the PHP 7.4+ short syntax, though I can't think of a good reason why... perhaps it's time.  It's a good suggestion because it actually will save a non-trivial number of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 24 bytes

```
psJ{{1j}qfcqpd}M-jNBL[!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/oNirutowq7YwLbmwIKXWVzfLz8knWlHx/39DBSMFY1MA)

```
ps     # Parse to list
J      # Duplicate
{
 {1j}  # Push 1 & swap
 qfc   # Find least common element
 qpd   # Product
}M-    # Create array applying each function to make each element
       # {{Original list}, 1, least common, product}
jNB    # Remove duplicates from original list
L[     # Find length
!!     # Select that element from the array 
       # (zero indexed, hence the push swap to fill zero)
```

## Burlesque, 31 bytes

```
psJU_qpd{f:{-]1==}fe[~}IEisq1if
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/oNgrNL6wIKU6zapaN9bQ1rY2LTW6rtbTNbO40DAz7f9/MwUgBAA)

Can probably be golfed further.

```
ps      # Parse to array
JU_     # (Non-destructive) is each element unique?
qpd     # boxed product
{
 f:     # Frequency (returns {{count val} ...})
 {
  -]1== # Count == 1
 }
 fe     # Find element where
 [~     # Take the tail
}
IE      # If unique then product, else find single
is      # Is an error (i.e. single not found)
q1      # boxed 1
if      # If error, push 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 40 bytes

```
f[l_]:=Times@@(If[Count[l,#]<2,#,1]&/@l)
```

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8tOic@1so2JDM3tdjBQcMzLdo5vzSvJDpHRznWxkhHWccwVk3fIUfzf0BRJlA4LbraUMdIx7g2NpYLLmKsYwwW@Q8A)!

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 26

```bash
sort|uniq -u|dc -e1?*?*?*p
```

The 3 input integers are each given on their own line.

In the case of non-distinct inputs, `dc` warnings are printed to stderr.  These may be ignored.

`uniq -u` does most of the heavy lifting here.  With the `-u` option, only non-duplicated lines are returned.  uniq requires its input to be `sort`ed.

The `dc` expression pushes 1 to the stack, then reads up to 3 integers, multiplying each in turn, then `p`rinting the output.  If uniq pipes less than 3 integers to dc, then the surplus `?` will not add to the stack and the following `*` will spit out a warning because * needs to pop 2 operands from the stack.  But these are just warnings, dc continues execution until it prints the final product.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYa9DkAwAAb3PsUXYZEYqJ/BYLIZxCaxoBVNpKUllr571V1yuWU2u3t3cXBoPrMaTBF4Ti3kvSGIzCQDhEPbdyMsJmeUvu0jxYXksWxFwtMm/j0dU5K7Cl5CQVGQDCVK/zkoSZH5fg)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```python
l=input();r=1
for x in l:r*=1%l.count(x)or x
print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU3LCsIwELzvV@xF2soitNUKlRzr1Ys/oHGlwZCEJcX262OCh2GGeTBhi7N3XdL@xaiwqqpklXFhiXVzEdXC2wuuaBzaUfaq3dmD9ouL9dqUAIIYF1FSHgJ8Z2MZ77LwCIhRtkKIvLLGcgBFaw4Rp9t1EvHyLzyFH590pp56yKATdDTQkPUxOy111P8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 38 bytes

```ruby
->*a{r=1;a.map{|w|(a-[w])[1]&&r*=w};r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcw9CoAwDAXgqziJlijUnzpIvUjIUAc3QQrSiu3ZY6gE3sd7Q/y9P3xY7jblXm/16vrTXW8KqXEdBmpRU117ZUNefWbEBeQIxBFGURJmcQADpvSp7BoGkf5vMV0VRjhQRaLMHw)

Answer (score 2):

## [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/), 60 bytes

```
int f(int a,int b,int c)=>a==b?a==c?1:c:a==c?b:b==c?a:a*b*c;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to code golf! I edited your submission to include the score, since we require that for all posts. I think you can save some bytes by removing some spaces. Good luck and I hope you enjoy your time here :)

Answer (score 2):

## TI BASIC, 45 Bytes

```
Prompt A,B,C
ABC
If A=B
C
If A=C
B
If B=C
A
If A=B and A=C
1
Ans
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `A=sqrt(BC)` is what you want...Suppose `A=12`, `B=9`, and `C=16`. Then `A=sqrt(BC)`, but `A!=B` and `A!=C`.

Comment: Yeah that might not be as clean as hoped.  I think you can also do prod(A={B,C but that comes out to the same bytes as A=B and A=C

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
≡ᵍ~gˢ×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/1Hnwodbe@vSTy86PP3//@hocx0FEIrViTbWUQAiUyDLSEfBDIggYiZAYSDLUEfBCMoC0pY6CoZmsbEA)

```
 ᵍ        Group elements by
≡         value.
    ˢ     For each group,
  ~g      if it is a singleton list, extract its only element,
    ˢ     else discard it.
     ×    Take the product.
```

Comment: I'm curious about the "select" (meta?)predicate and your explanation. I am having trouble following as the explanation (and my brief glance at the documentation) makes it seem a bit like just a mapping. When/why does it discard results and what does `~g` do for non-singleton lists?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman The difference between `xᵐ` and `xˢ` (where `x` is any predicate) is that, if `x` fails on any element, `xᵐ` fails in its entirety, but `xˢ` discards any and all elements which fail instead. Failing is also what `~g` does given a non-singleton list (`g` wraps its input into a singleton list, `~` inverts it). The utility of failure is backtracking to the most recent choice-point, and `ˢ` [has one internally](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/blob/2efca3d804ee8a30c231bf5974d1e9d6dfae267c/src/metapredicates.pl#L568) for that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `sets.extras math.unicode`, 20 bytes

```
[ non-repeating Π ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYpLCgIxEAX3c4p3AQMz/lAPIG7ciCtx0cRWg0wSkx5QhrmLJ/JKMYq/Lt6iqN6TFhfSerVYzqeILFHxRQJF1CRH1Vij3Y5zODdsNUf4wCJXH4wVzIqiLZCvxfhF97Z@Zvi1CqPMrw3yPlbm@mcVJiifv13awDrbC@yZxNgD7jdsU00eUUifVHoA)

Factor has a word `non-repeating` that gives you every element of a sequence that doesn't repeat. Turns out the answer to this question is just taking the product of this.

Answer (score 2):

## MMIX, 48 bytes (12 instrs)

```
foo CMP $255,$0,$1
    CMP $3,$1,$2
    BZ  $255,0F     // if(a == b) goto ab
    BZ  $3,1F       // if(b == c) goto bc
    CMP $255,$0,$2
    BZ  $255,2F     // if(a == c) goto ac
    MUL $0,$0,$1    // a *= b
    MUL $0,$0,$2    // a *= c
1H  POP 1,0         // bc: return a
0H  CSZ $2,$3,1     // ab: if(b == c) c = 1
    POP 3,0         // return c
2H  POP 2,0         // ac: return b
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
cḅịp
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWMlRTElQjglODUlRTElQkIlOEJwJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JTVCNyUyQyUyMDclMkMlMjA3JTVEJTIwLSUzRSUyMDElMEElNUIzJTJDJTIwMyUyQyUyMDUlNUQlMjAtJTNFJTIwNSUwQSU1QjIlMkMlMjA2JTJDJTIwNiU1RCUyMC0lM0UlMjAyJTBBJTVCMyUyQyUyMDQlMkMlMjAzJTVEJTIwLSUzRSUyMDQlMEElNUIxJTJDJTIwMiUyQyUyMDMlNUQlMjAtJTNFJTIwNiUwQSU1QjEyJTJDJTIwOSUyQyUyMDE2JTVEJTIwLSUzRSUyMDE3MjgmZmxhZ3M9Qw==)

##### Explanation

```python
cḅịp  # Implicit input
c     # Counts of each number
  ị   # Only keep items of the input
 ḅ    # where the count equals 1
   p  # Product of this list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=product -apl`, <s>45</s> 44 bytes

*@FryAmTheEggman saves a byte*

```perl
$_=product(grep{$t=$_;2>grep$t==$_,@F}@F)||1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ragKD@lNLlEI70otaBapcRWJd7ayA7EAbKBHB0Ht1oHN82aGsP/1qrZthqa1v/NFYCQy1jBWMGUy0jBTMEMyDZRMOYyVDBSMP6XX1CSmZ9X/F/X1yezuMTKKrQkMwdmyX/dxIIcAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>9</s> 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ü l1 ×
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=/CBsMSDX&input=WwpbNywgNywgN10KWzMsIDMsIDVdClsyLCA2LCA2XQpbMywgNCwgM10KWzEsIDIsIDNdCl0tbVI)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 97 bytes

```powershell
param($n)$a,$b,$c=$n|group;(($n-join'*'|iex),(($a,$b|?{$_.count-eq1}).name,1)[$a.count-eq3])[!$c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcpRCsIwDADQswiBNZINxvRLZN5jDIkl6GRLa3UoWM8e54@/jxfDU9L9IuNoFjnx5EARmOBE4Peg@ZzCHHdu4fIaBi3WRR7khbTIb@X2DcfKh1kfpdzqD1bKk1CNHfCfmx67FfjezA6uoS1t8As)

Not terribly impressive, but given that PowerShell doesn't have a ternary operator like JavaScript, nor the same `for` structure as Python, I don't think this is too bad.

We take input `$n` as an array, then feed that into `Group-Object`, which stores the (potentially) three values into `$a, $b, $c`. Then we use array-indexing as a pseudo-ternary. We work "backwards" on the function definition given in the challenge, starting from the bottom. If we have a `$c`, then we have three unique values, so we `-join` `$n` with `*` and `iex` it (similar to `eval`). Otherwise, we have at least a duplicate, so we re-index whether `$a`'s `.count` is `-eq`ual to `3`. If it is, then all three values are the same, and we output `1`. Otherwise, we pull out the lonely value (i.e., its `.count` is `-eq`ual to `1`) and output its `.name`. In any case, the result is left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
ＩΠＥθ⎇⊖№θι¹ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI6AoP6U0uUTDN7FAo1BHISS1KC@xqFLDJTW5KDU3Na8kNUXDOb8UqBoomampqaNgCKaBwPr//@hoSx0FEIqN/a9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   θ        Input array
  Ｅ         Map over elements
      №     Count of
        ι   Current element
       θ    In input array
     ⊖      Decremented
    ⎇       Ternary
          ι If count was 1 then original element
         ¹  Otherwise literal 1
 Π          Take the product
Ｉ           Cast to string for implicit print
```

I found other ways of formulating the condition, but they were all the same length. Alternate approach, also 11 bytes:

```
ＩΠ∨Φθ⁼¹№θι¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI6AoP6U0uUTDv0jDLTOnJLVIo1BHwbWwNDGnWMNQR8E5vxSoEiiUqampqaNgCCQ1rf//j4621FEAodjY/7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    θ       Input array
   Φ        Filter where
       №    Count of
         ι  Current element
        θ   In input array
     ⁼      Equals
      ¹     Literal 1
  ∨         Or if list is now empty
          ¹ Then literal 1
 Π          Take the product
Ｉ           Cast to string for implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 51 bytes

```
N`\d+
\b(\d+)(,\1)+\b

~["^.*¶$.("|""]'_L$`\d+
$&$*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8N8vISZFmysmSQNIaWroxBhqasckcXHVRSvF6Wkd2qaip6FUo6QUqx7vowJWqaKmovX/v7kOEHIZ6xjrmHIZ6ZjpmAHZJjrGXIY6RjrGAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
N`\d+
```

Sort the input list.

```
\b(\d+)(,\1)+\b
```

Delete all duplicated numbers.

```
L`\d+
```

List all the remaining numbers, discarding any commas.

```
$`
$&$*
```

Suffix each number with a `*`.

```
|""`
```

Don't separate the numbers.

```
["^.*¶$.("`
```

Prefix the result with `^.*` on its own line and `$.(` on the same line as the numbers.

```
]'_`
```

Suffix the result with a `_`.

```
~`
```

Evaluate the result on the previous contents of the buffer. This results in one of three evaluations:

1. If all three numbers were identical, it evaluates this:

   ```
   ^.*
   $.(_
   ```
2. If two numbers were identical, it evaluates this:

   ```
   ^.*
   $.(5*_
   ```
3. If the numbers were distinct, it evaluates this:

   ```
   ^.*
   $.(1*2*3*_
   ```

This takes the string `_`, and repeats it by the remaining numbers in turn, and then takes the length of the result, which is exactly the same as the product of the numbers, or 1 if there were none left.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 39 bytes

```sh
(){i=1
for n;((i*=${(M)#@:#$n}>1?1:n))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J9WmpdckpmfV6yg66uQxpUW819DszrT1pArLb9IIc9aQyNTy1alWsNXU9nBSlklr9bO0N7QKk9Ts/Z/anJGvoKKhoZCmoahjpGOsaaCpiYXkqARdkFjTEFjmOB/AA)

For the first time, I can say that a zsh math function actually won out over a normal program! I knew there was potential when I got a tie a while back, [here's the relevant meta post if you want to know more about them.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18212/zsh-functions-and-math-functions)

The meat of this is the loop where we test for distinctness:

```sh
${(M)#@:#$n}
${   #     }    # count
${(M)      }    # matches
${    @:#  }    # on the positional parameters.
${       $n}    # against $n
            >1  # more than 1 (not distinct)
```

We use a ternary to decide to multiply by 1 or n.

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 178 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Dupe_0][T    N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input_A][S N
S _Dupe_input_A][S N
S _Dupe_input_A][T  N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input_B][S N
S _Dupe_input_B][S N
S _Dupe_input_B][T  N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input_C][S N
S _Dupe_input_C][S T    S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_input_B][T    S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_C==B][S N
S _Dupe_input_C][S T    S S T   T   N
_Copy_0-based_3rd_input_A][T    S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S T N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_C!=B&&C==A][S T S S T   S N
_Push_0-based_2nd_input_A][S T  S S T   S N
_Push_0-based_2nd_input_B][T    S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_PRINT][T    S S N
_Multiply][T    S S N
_Multiply][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_PRINT][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_C!=B&&C==A][S N
N
_Discard_input_C][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_PRINT][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_C==B][S N
S _Dupe_input_C][S T    S S T   T   N
_Copy_0-based_3rd_input_A][T    S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S T T   N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_C==B&&C==A][S N
N
_Discard_input_C][S N
N
_Discard_input_B][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_PRINT][N
S S T   T   N
_Create_Label_C==B&&C==A][S S S T   N
_Push_1][N
S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QQDIwsPhBCEuEAkiuGBCnDAhTi6oElSVYMUgDNTBBdIDocFsbKaA5RFKQHyQDMg1IBv@/zc04rI05jI0AgA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Whitespace work-flow:**

```
Integer A = STDIN as integer
Integer B = STDIN as integer
Integer C = STDIN as integer                   (the stack now contains [A,B,C])
If(C==B): Jump to Label C==B
If(C==A): Jump to Label C!=B&&C==A
If(A==B): Jump to Label PRINT                  (top of the stack is here C)
Multiply top two
Multiply top two
Jump to Label PRINT                            (top of the stack is here A*B*C)

Label C!=B&&C==A:
  Discard top (C)
  Jump to Label PRINT                          (top of the stack is here B)
Label C==B:
  If(C==A): Jump to Label C==B&&C==A
  Discard top (C)
  Discard top (B)
  Jump to Label PRINT                          (top of the stack is here A)

Label C==B&C==A
  Push 1                                       (top of the stack is here 1)
Label PRINT
  Print top of the stack as integer to STDOUT
```

Since the inputs are guaranteed to be positive, it uses heap-address `0` for input `A`; heap-address `A` for input `B`; and heap-address `B` for input `C`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>52 51</s> 43 bytes

```
filter{z->count{z==it}<2}.fold(1){s,c->s*c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BCoJAEIbvPsUcd2MT3NQgXO9B0TOIaSxNY@gY5OKzb9stxIbvMvDx/feO0ZJ/VQgnO3BxJC5j7KjB93lEPoQ/ujUspPGtRW56N23LuhuJ3WSM5bnQc9x2eBWJdIOqt@WwqWffjgSPypKQ4CII9@wtMZLAMHJpxV7BF/kzBcZAItfknYJAtpSzVVkryANLWUv4k05DfWmnq@lEgV6RcxnN/gM)

Comment: Not sure if defining the function in the header like I did is allowed, if it isn't i'll have to go back to the 51 byte answer

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
äùóq◘0Jg•UÜ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8497a27108304a6707559a&i=%5B7,7,7%5D%0A%5B3,3,5%5D%0A%5B2,6,6%5D%0A%5B3,4,3%5D%0A%5B1,2,3%5D%0A%5B12,9,16%5D&m=2)

This one works for all testcases, and shorter! Uses Unrelated String's idea.

### Explanation

```
o{}/{Dz_?m$:*
o             order the array
 {}/          group equal adjacent values
    {    m    map to the following:
        ?     if:
     D        deleting the first element
              makes the array empty, then:
       _       push it again
      z        otherwise push an empty list
          $   flatten the result
           :* take the product
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```scala
f=>f.filter(i=>f.count(_==i)<2).product
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDNasMwEITveYrB@CCBYrCbv4bI0GMPPeVYSpFtqShxZddWSsD42d2NmoNbaZGW@XYGob5UtZqa4qRLjxdlHfTVa1f1eGpbDItvVcPscdRfr8/Ov0HmoBtyMjI3ibG11x2zt75sLs6zdyktP2Q8abumupR@Mk1HMaDFlCg4DstbGAsKQrsVtDmWOVIxkx8EqNYBrOcgE9hQBZD9c6zIFMBqDlJBg3ew@QNIfhRIf8PSbbYLkNM53l/ddtb52rE@MiweVPJ5PnqSPlgkIj4GXzwYpvgIpq8tfaOu9ogLHoWUxTj9AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>199</s> 100 bytes

```c
a,b;main(c){scanf("%i%i%i",&a,&b,&c);printf("%i",a-b|b-c?a-b|b==c?b-c|c==a?a-c|c==b?a*b*c:b:a:c:1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYnLDsIgFER/hWAkpQETo26gyLfcO/VBUtHYdmX9dqxkFnPmDCwGyreySRnD3F9EN059eu7u50KG/YNSbqA/IyhfG7lN/0ijyCg2Ctq/3ilP9ZGGLC9sEWuHgLiOBSHQaipwpJZbOHbk4Pbaf0s5iaM4/AA)

Don't know C? Here's how it works. We initialize 3 integers, give them input, then proceeds to multiple if-statements to check whether or not they're equal.

Thanks to ceilingcat for golfing a **whopping** 99 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
Ċ't1=;f1JΠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C4%8A%27t1%3D%3Bf1J%CE%A0&inputs=%5B7%2C7%2C7%5D&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 118 Bytes

This `function` uses the set-member-iteration statement (`for … in … do`) and the symmetric difference operator `><`.
Therefore it needs a processor at least supporting features of ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal” (level 0).

```pascal
function f(a,b,c:integer):integer;var r:integer;begin r:=1;if[a,b,c]<>[a]then for a in[a]><[b]><[c]do r:=r*a;f:=r end;
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
function f(a, b, c: integer): integer;
var
    result: integer;
begin
    { `result` needs to be initialized for the `for`-loop below. }
    result := 1;
    
    { If not sidelengths of an equilateral triangle: }
    if [a, b, c] <> [a] then
    begin
        { Symmetric difference of sets. }
        for a in [a] >< [b] >< [c] do
        begin
            result := result * a;
        end;
        { NB: The iterator variable `a` retains its original value
          unless you escape the `for`-statement with a `goto`. }
    end;
    
    { In Pascal there must be _exactly_ one assignment
      to the implicitly declared variable bearing the function’s name.
      Hence we cannot simply re-use `f` as the `result` variable. }
    f := result;
end;
```

Comment: I'm not the most familiar with Pascal, but I'm surprised that the initial `if` block is needed. If `a=b=c` then shouldn't the for loop be over an empty list leaving the result as 1?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman There are _three_ factors. Using mathematical notation, consider A = {7} = B = C (the first test case given in the task specification). The expression A △ B does indeed yield ∅ (empty set). However, after that ∅ △ C will then yield {7}. Hence you will need to guard the `for … in`‑loop.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I somewhat overthought it and clumped the two operations into one.

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 74 bytes

```lisp
λ(n)(apply *(map(λ(x)(if(=(length x)1)(car x)1))(group-by identity n))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RclBDoIwFATQPaeYxIXzTVwAiisPU6HFxlqbpib0bN7BK1UkEv9s5s2Pqr/pVDZO@RFxQcVBG@s1DMv7RS9UIbiMHe8qcF4moTU802k/pismqYW9iksRjvHxDPtLhh20TzZleJmvSEWDLU@YIz@0aHFc0aBD9/8c0K6o0XxRPg)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 60 bytes

```
=IF(A1=B1,IF(A1=C1,1,C1),IF(B1=C1,A1,IF(A1=C1,B1,A1*B1*C1)))
```

Does not use features like `FILTER`, only available to Office Insiders.

Answer (score 0):

### SQL, <s>245</s> 155 bytes

```sql
 DECLARE @a INT=2,@b INT=4,@c INT=8;WITH v AS(SELECT x FROM(VALUES(@a),(@b),(@c))t(x) GROUP BY x HAVING COUNT(*)=1)SELECT ISNULL(EXP(SUM(LOG(x))), 1) FROM v
```

Expanded:

```sql
DECLARE @a INT=2,
        @b INT=4,
        @c INT=8;

WITH v
     AS (SELECT x
           FROM(VALUES(@a),
                      (@b),
                      (@c))t(x)
          GROUP BY x
         HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
SELECT ISNULL(EXP(SUM(LOG(x))), 1)
  FROM v
```

The straightforward solution is only 150 .. but it is boring. :)

```sql
DECLARE @a INT=2,@b INT=4,@c INT=2;SELECT CASE WHEN @a=@b AND @a=@c THEN 1 WHEN @a=@b THEN @c WHEN @b=@c THEN @a WHEN @a=@c THEN @b ELSE @a*@b*@c END
```

```sql
DECLARE @a INT=2,
        @b INT=4,
        @c INT=2;

SELECT CASE
         WHEN @a = @b
              AND @a = @c THEN 1
         WHEN @a = @b THEN @c
         WHEN @b = @c THEN @a
         WHEN @a = @c THEN @b
         ELSE @a * @b * @c
       END
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with SQL golfing, but the `DECLARE` statement seems out of place. I feel as though it either shouldn't be part of the answer, or what you've written isn't precisely reusable? I could easily be wrong - I'm just stating my current understanding.

Comment: Fair point - I am uncertain as well.. I can "assume" the @a, @b, and @c are the parameters passed into a function whose body is the SELECT statement, but is that correct? I could use some guidance there as well.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
üΩ1↑♂Åò←3♠'W▐
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81ea31180b8f951b33062757de&i=5+5+5)

Comment: Thanks for your post! Unfortunately this doesn't seem to meet the requirements for the case where two of the numbers are the same (i.e. for `5 5 7` this returns 35 when it should return 7). Since I don't understand Stax myself, it would also be great if you could include an explanation of what approach your code is using.

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, 7 bytes

```
/×⊚=1°⊚
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__ZiDihpAgL8OX4oqaPTHCsOKKmgoKZiBbNyA3IDddCmYgWzMgMyA1XQpmIFsyIDYgNl0KZiBbMyA0IDNdCmYgWzEgMiAzXQpmIFsxMiA5IDE2XQo=)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,b,c)=>a>f||f(b,c,[a])*(a-b&&a-c?a:1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9mC0QaiTpJOsmatnaJdmk1NWkaQI5OdGKsppZGom6SmlqibrJ9opWh5v/k/Lzi/JxUvZz8dI00DXMdBRDS1FTQ11cw5EKVNNZRACJTiKQpmqSRjoIZEEEkjTB1mgA1QyRN0CQNdRSM4JJm/wE)

For shorter solution Arnauld has a 38 one